# Magento2.2.6 How to redirect url after pass parameter?

Tags: url-rewrite, admin-panel, magento2.2.6

I have using Magento2.2.6 I have tried to add URL rewrites into Magento 2 using the Marketing -> Url Rewrite tool.

The old URLs for the store look like this:

```
group.asp?group=320
```

http://XXXXXXX/magento231/catalogsearch/result/?q=test

I can enter that into the Request Path just fine, but anything with a ? in it never actually forwards to the Target Path. If I remove the ?, it redirects fine.. but obviously that is not a valid URL.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: try using .htaccess file

Comment: try:  group.asp/group/320

Comment: @RonakChauhan I have tried this but redirect is not working.

Comment: @JimitBhavsar I have so many URL's to redirect so I can't use .htaccess need to fix by using Magento URL Rewrite Functionality.

Comment: you can override URL rewrite module and implement code in Router.php

Comment: @Devidas can you explain me how to rewrite or implement code in router.php?Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

I have found that solutions for my questions.Below define in root .htaccess file inside code use it

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*q=hhh.*$
RewriteRule .* /magento231? [R=301,NC,L]


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=123$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /magento231/test-category.html [QSD,R=301,L]
```